# MY SQL Query Join and search via corresponding ids

Tags: mysql, join

I have no experience with SQL but apparently it is the only way to achieve what I am after.

I have two tables one called `pp_users` and the other `pp_userdata`

`pp_users` contains information on each user of the site. Each user has an ID and an email address along with some additional information. The column structure is.

```
ID  -  user_email
```

pp_userdata contains additional information in the form of meta_keys with an id that corresponds to the ID in pp_users. So the structure shows a series of additional information for each user ID. The format is.

```
meta_id   -   user_id   -   meta_key   -   meta_value
```

The two meta keys that we are after are the value of `first_name` and `last_name`

So the intention is to get each user in `pp_users` and then order them by the the `meta_key last_name` using the corresponding `user_id` in `pp_userdata`.

After some reading I believe this required the two tables to JOIN but I have no idea how to get a `meta_key` by corresponding `user_id`.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join syntax to get a result set like:

```
+------+------------------+----------+-----------+
| id   | user_email       | lastname | firstname |
+------+------------------+----------+-----------+
|    1 | test@example.com | Doe      | John      |
+------+------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Would be:

```
 SELECT    id, 
           user_email, 
           meta_lastname.meta_value lastname,  
           meta_firstname.meta_value firstname 
 FROM      pp_users 
 LEFT JOIN pp_userdata meta_lastname 
 ON        meta_lastname.user_id = pp_users.id 
 LEFT JOIN pp_userdata meta_firstname 
 ON        meta_firstname.user_id = pp_users.id 
 WHERE     meta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' 
 AND       meta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name'
```

This query joins to the `pp_userdata` table multiple times, with different aliases (here the aliases are `meta_firstname` and `meta_lastname`). You can do this as many times as you like to get values from your metadata table - one join per key type. If you keep the alias names meaningful it's easy to keep track of which joined table is providing which columns in the result.

Comment: Brilliant. How though would we then order it by the last name. I tried  and it returned an error - ORDER BY meta_lastname WHERE user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%';"); Also how do I then fetch the lastname value. With user_email I would use while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
 $email = $row['user_email'];

Comment: To order by a column, just do `ORDER BY <position>`, so for `lastname` in my example, do `ORDER BY 4` - you can also do this by their *aliased* column names, so `ORDER BY lastname` will work also. `meta_lastname` is just the alias I used for the `pp_userdata` table when fetching the lastname. The column itself is aliased as just `lastname` which is how you see it in the result set.  Fetching the values can be done using your existing `$row` array - `lastname` becomes `$row['lastname']`.

Comment: I tried this but the script is returning an error  ORDER BY lastname WHERE user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%';");

Comment: Your `ORDER BY` needs to be at the very end of the query - it can't come before your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I'm still struggling. Its all in the last line as when I take it out the script does work although not in order or correct to the search terms. It's this line WHERE user_email LIKE '%$searchpattern%' 
 ORDER BY lastname;

Comment: If you post your whole query, I'll have a look

Comment: I've looked into it. I had a double WHERE Query but I now have a new problem that has this error code #1054 - Unknown column 'lastname' in 'where clause'

Comment: In the instance of the `pp_userdata` table that you're using to get the lastname, how have you aliased the column? In my example I did `SELECT .. meta_lastname.meta_value lastname ... ` - The `pp_userdata` table is aliased as `meta_lastname`, and the `meta_value` column is aliased as `lastname`. If you've aliased it differently, the `lastname` won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the meta_users rows associated with a given user, you can use the following query.

```
select meta_users.* 
from pp_users
join meta_users
on pp_users.id = meta_users.user_id
where user_id = (some user ID here);
```

To get a specific key related to a given user, you can make it more specific.

```
select meta_users.* 
from pp_users
join meta_users
on pp_users.id = meta_users.user_id
where user_id = (some user ID here)
and meta_key = (some key name here);
```

To order by last name:

```
select meta_users.* 
from pp_users
join meta_users
on pp_users.id = meta_users.user_id
where user_id = (some user ID here)
and meta_key = 'last_name'
order by meta_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_id, a.meta_key, a.meta_value, b.meta_key, b.meta_value
FROM pp_users u
JOIN pp_userdata a ON u.ID = a.user_id AND a.meta_key='last_name'
JOIN pp_userdata b ON u.ID = b.user_id AND b.meta_key='first_name'
ORDER BY a.meta_value
```

Alternatively you can move the `first_name` and `last_name part` to the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_id, a.meta_key, a.meta_value, b.meta_key, b.meta_value
FROM pp_users u
JOIN pp_userdata a ON u.ID = a.user_id 
JOIN pp_userdata b ON u.ID = b.user_id
WHERE a.meta_key='last_name' AND b.meta_key='first_name'
ORDER BY a.meta_value
```